# Undefined reference to mapnik::hit_grid from C++ compile?

Tags: mapnik, c++

I am trying to compile a c++ mapnik program with code in question being:

```
mapnik::grid my_grid(256, 256, "id");
```

and the command to compile being:

```
g++ grid_gen.cpp -std=c++11 -lmapnik -lcairo -lfreetype -lpng -licuuc -lz -ldl -Wall -o grid_gen
```

which ends up throwing this error:

> grid_gen.cpp:(.text+0x744): undefined reference to
>   `mapnik::hit_grid<mapnik::gray32s_t>::hit_grid(unsigned long, unsigned
>   long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
>   std::allocator<char> > const&)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.2 with g++ 5.4.0.

How do I compile this without throwing any error?

If you are curious, I am trying to generate utf8 grid for the map tiles from c++.

Answer (score 0):

Searching through the mapnik code base, brought me to the file include/mapnik/value/types.hpp, which had this code:

```
#ifdef BIGINT
//using value_integer = boost::long_long_type;
//using value_integer = long long;
using value_integer = std::int64_t;
using value_integer_pixel = gray64s_t;
#else
//using value_integer = int;
using value_integer = std::int32_t;
using value_integer_pixel = gray32s_t;
#endif
```

I am on a 64 bit system. I have defined a constant BIGINT

```
#define BIGINT 1
```

in the script and code is compiling without errors now. Don't know if this is acceptable.